# Dynamic / Regex params in ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters, applicationcontroller

How to permit dynamic params in an AppicationController?

so **all** these parameters should permitted:

```
params = { "filter_color" => "blue,green", 
           "filter_size" => "xl,sm,lg", 
           "filter_type" => "new,old,used",
           "limit" => "10" }
```

But my approach only passes `limit`,

```
def product_params
  params.permit(:limit, /filter_.*/)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`permit` method only processes an incoming value if it's a Symbol, String, or Hash](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-1-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L597).

If you want to try to work around this you could do something like this:

```rb
filter_names = params.keys.select { |key| key[/\Afilter_.*/] }
params.permit(:limit, *filter_names)
```

But be aware that the point of [Strong Parameters](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) is to define an explicit set of allowed values to avoid security problems with mass-assigning user-provided values.  As long as it's always safe to allow any user to pass in any kind of `filter_*` value, then you should be OK.